# Does a character suffer negative effects from using a Wish spell cast from a magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

One of my characters recently received the *luck blade* magic item with 2 wishes in it. The description of the *luck blade* (DMG, p. 179) states:

> ***Wish.*** The sword has 1d4–1 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 charge and cast the *wish* spell from it. This property can't be used again until the next dawn. The sword loses this property if it has no charges.

The spell is cast **from** the item.

Would my character suffer the negative effects of wishing for anything besides duplicating another spell, since it states the spell is cast from the *luck blade*?

Comment: [Related] [Wish on a scroll: Who suffers the consequences?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65508)

Comment: Is your question specifically about the *luck blade*, or any item that grants the ability to cast *wish*, or any item that grants the effect of *wish*?

Comment: @V2Blast This user was last active two years ago - I'd be surprised if clarification was forthcoming.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [*luck blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5393-luck-blade) (DMG, p. 179) says:

> you [...] cast the *wish* spell from it.

The [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell may be cast from the blade, but *you* are still the one casting it. Therefore, you would still suffer the negative effects of wishing for anything besides copying a spell:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than
> duplicating another spell weakens you. [...]

The same applies to any other magic item that says "you cast" the *wish* spell from it.

Comment: A later duplicate ([Do you "suffer stress" even if you use a wish from an item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108618)) has an answer citing the DMG re: casting a spell "from an item" definitely counting as casting it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

### In a quote, "It is not hands that summon us. It is desire!"

Powerful uses of the Wish spell are exceptionally strenuous as spelled out in the spell. Whether you are casting it from a scroll, from a ring, from a magic sword, or even straight from your mind all that matters is **you** are casting it and that kind of mojo has a price.