# Does the wish-granting Efreeti from an Efreeti Bottle suffer wish stress?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

There is a small chance that an efreeti released by this item has the following effect:

> The efreeti can cast the wish spell three times for you. It disappears when it grants the final wish or after 1 hour, and the bottle loses its magic. (— DMG 167)

Would this creature be subject to wish-related stress?

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way. In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33 percent
>   chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you suffer this stress.
>    (— PHB 289)

If so, there would be more than a 70% (19/27) chance that the Efreeti becomes incapable of casting wish if given three wishes that trigger this stress to grant.

Comment: [Related] [Magic Items with Wishes in them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74333)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Maybe, but the *efreeti bottle* still works as written

Specific beats general, and the rules surrounding the *efreeti bottle* specifically state under what conditions the efreeti no longer grants the owner wishes, as you quoted above. Thus, the efreeti doesn't suffer an effect that would prevent it from fulfilling its services before it disappears (after casting the *wish* spell three times or after 1 hour, whichever is first).

Comment: The rules surrounding the efreeti bottle state the conditions under which it disappears not ones where it stops granting wishes. It says it *can* cast wish for you, not that it *must* cast it for you, or even obey you. It might do so in order to leave sooner. Nothing explicitly prevents effects that would prevent it from fulfilling services. (e.g. "I wish you can't cast *wish* anymore.")

Comment: You got out of scope there. Of course DM fiat or the PC wrecking things will change how the item may work.Doesn't mean it needs to be mentioned in every question. In fact doing so would be counterproductive.

Answer (score 9):

#### No, they don't suffer the stress of casting *wish*.

The weakness you mention from casting *wish* comes from the PHB and doesn't necessarily apply to monsters.  You might be interested in reading the ["Variant: Genie Powers" sidebar for Genies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Djinni) in the *Monster Manual* (p. 144).  It limits noble genies to granting 1-3 wishes to a non-genie with a 1-year recharge, and that genie can never grant wishes to that creature ever again.

Based on genie lore through the editions, I think it is reasonable to assume that genies have a significantly different relationship with *wish* than any other creature type (short of deities).  In the *Pathfinder* setting of Golarion, there was even a Wish War between the genies.

Comment: **Variant: Genie Powers** still requires genies to cast the *wish* spell, and doesn't indicate any exceptions to the spell's effect.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it suffers the stress of casting *wish*

Why do you think 90% can’t cast *wish*?

D&D 5e does what it says it does: they cast *wish*, with all the benefits and risks this entails. Nothing in the rules specifies that it doesn't suffer the stress of casting *wish*, so it does.

Comment: May be worth noting that not all wishes involve stress, since the question seems to be missing that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the OP doesn’t miss that - it’s in the last sentence. Anyway, what player, when granted a wish casting efreet uses it to duplicate a spell? In practice they are all going to cause stress.

Comment: Mm, I'd read that last sentence as ambiguous, but fair enough. As to that rhetorical: resurrection and teleport come to mind as spells that fulfill some classic wishes.