# Do genies suffer the side effects of the Wish spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, wish

In the section on [genies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Genies) in the *Monster Manual* (p. 141), it says that noble genies can grant wishes. The ["Variant: Genie Powers"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Djinni) sidebar (p. 144) details this variant rule, but doesn't mention anything about [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)'s side effects on the caster.

In accordance with legends, and the way that the text describes it, surely these genies aren’t risking losing the ability to cast the *wish* spell every time they grant a wish, right? Or else, why would a genie ever agree to grant a wish (unless they only ever duplicated the effect of an 8th-level spell or below)?

Comment: At least highly related: [Does the wish-granting Efreeti from an Efreeti Bottle suffer wish stress?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112967/52137)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### They can suffer the side effects of casting *wish*

The specific wording in the ["Variant: Genie Powers"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Djinni) sidebar (MM, p. 144) is:

> The genie can then cast the *wish* spell on the creature's behalf to bring about the effect.

Since there are no hidden rules, the *wish* spell is the *wish* spell and the genie is subject to all the same consequences as anyone else.

> ... surely these genies aren’t risking losing the ability to cast the *wish* spell every time they grant a wish, right?

Well, no. But then no one does unless they try to do something "beyond the scope of the above examples".

> Or else, why would a genie ever agree to grant a wish?

Why, indeed?

Presumably for all the same reasons that anyone might. Therefore, it is extremely unlikely that a genie would take this risk unless they were somehow motivated to by inducement or coercion.

Putting aside D&D, genies in folklore have never been really keen to grant wishes. Now you know why.

Comment: This probably why Genies only give 3 wishes.