# Can the stress of wish prevent using wishes from other sources?

Tags: dnd-5e, wish

The stress of casting *wish* for creative effects has a 1/3 chance of preventing the caster from ever casting *wish* again.  (There are plenty of cites all over RPG Exchange.)  Does this preclude using wishes from sources that *do not* involve the PC casting *wish*?

---

Related:
[Does a character suffer negative effects from using a Wish spell cast from a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74333/does-a-character-suffer-negative-effects-from-using-a-wish-spell-cast-from-a-mag) — This question addresses an item that enables the PC "to cast the *wish* spell from it".

[Do the negative effects of wish apply to free wishes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167330/do-the-negative-effects-of-wish-apply-to-free-wishes) — This question's second bullet point is similar to my question, but is phrased as being able to use items' properties that enable a PC to cast *wish*.

[Does the wish-granting Efreeti from an Efreeti Bottle suffer wish stress?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112967/does-the-wish-granting-efreeti-from-an-efreeti-bottle-suffer-wish-stress) — This discusses whether an efreeti granting a *wish* suffers wish stress.  This approaches my question:  Can a PC that cannot cast *wish* due to the stress have their wish fulfilled by an efreeti or similar?

(This question arose from a dream I had last night:  Dream-me took a ring that I had collected during my adventuring days.  This was not a *Ring of Three Wishes*, rather a ring like the lamp in "Aladdin's Wonderful Lamp" from *Arabian Nights*: The host vessel for a djinni that could grant wishes without numerical limit.  I was negotiating with the djinni on the phrasing of a *wish* that would cancel the contagious aspect of SARS-CoV-2; the djinni told me that if I wished for that, I would never be able to use a wish ever again.  I was willing to pay that price; wouldn't you?)

Comment: I'm not sure how the related links you put in aren't duplicates. Can you explain further how your question is different?

Comment: As I understand it, two of the linked questions address a PC casting _wish_ from an item, and the third is whether an efreeti suffers stress from _wish_.  I am asking about the case between those questions.

Comment: Can you clarify that case? The "free" wishes question includes 3rd parties (as also seen in the answer) - how is that not the same?

Comment: @Medix2 Right, and that seems to be the question about free wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *You* cannot cast *wish*, even through a magic item; this does not affect anybody who casts *wish* on your behalf

The [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell states:

> [...]  Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast *wish* ever again if you suffer this stress.

This clause affects *only* the caster, it does not impact anybody else. You, the caster, cannot cast *wish* ever again; it has no effect on whether an Efreeti can cast a *wish* for or whether somebody can cast *wish* from a scroll you made.

Given that you cannot cast *wish* you also cannot use any magic items that allow you to cast *wish* because in that case you are *still* casting *wish*, the very thing you cannot do. The fact that you are still the caster is gone over in more detail in the following question:

- [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50054)