# Do you "suffer stress" even if you use a wish from an item?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

If you use a [ring of 3 wishes](https://open5e.com/equipment/magic-items/ring-of-three-wishes.html) or a [luckblade](https://open5e.com/equipment/magic-items/luck-blade.html) for a wish (not emulating a spell) do you "suffer stress" - specifically the 33% chance of never casting wish again?

Comment: Related: [Wish on a scroll: Who suffers the consequences?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65508/wish-on-a-scroll-who-suffers-the-consequences)

Comment: @Erik you are correct. DUPE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RAW, yes. As indicated [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74333/magic-items-with-wishes-in-them).

DMG Page 141 indicates what is different from an item that allows you to cast a spell and casting the spell yourself. In this case you actually do cast Wish and suffer all the good and bad that comes with it.

DM fiat not withstanding since my last DM ignored that part of wish.